# SonarQube rule S1451 "Copyright and license headers should be defined" - no regex for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, rule

Our project uses both Java and JavaScript, for Java we have configured this rule to use a regular expression so that we don't have to hard-code copyright dates.

However, when activating the rule for JavaScript the configuration does not have the "isRegularExpression" configuration so it doesn't seem I can do the same here.

The rule appears to only allow static text and what's more appears to required the whole header (from start of header comment to end). I think this is so because I tried a workaround of settign the text to look for to...

```
  /**
    * Copyright (c)
```

(stopping short of the dates) but that did not work.
Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a ticket https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-531, it should be fixed in next version of plugin (2.14)

Comment: Thanks Elena - maybe we'll use a hard-coded whole line at the moment and keep an eye on this ticket (if we don't implement custom rule).

Answer (score 0):

The [current rule](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-javascript/blob/master/javascript-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/javascript/checks/FileHeaderCheck.java) for FileHeaderCheck contains the following code which shows it is looking for a full line match. So it doesn't require the full comment to match, but it does require the full line. Which doesn't help you here. If your comment has multiple lines, it could though. Because you could set the rule to match the second line which wouldn't change by year.

```
if (!line.equals(expectedLines[i])) {
```

The JavaScript rule plugin [allows extending the rules](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Extending+Coding+Rules) using Java. Which means you could write your own rule to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Jeanne we'll take a look at that, looks interesting :)

Comment: @Sid glad you found both my and Elena's answer helpful. Feel free to upvote both. That's the way to show appreciation on stack overflow. (It's also traditional to accept one of the answers to show you got an answer)

Comment: actually, that failed for me. Then when I did a little more research and found (I think) a copy of the of the header check source and where I took you to mean 'I only need to provide one line from the header' the reality is that you need to 'provide all of the lines of the header from the start, down to and including the line you want to actually check'.   p.s. thanks for highlighting the points on use of forum, I'm new to this :)

Comment: Oh. Reading the code again I see that now. Sorry for the bad info. And you're welcome on the tip on using the forum. Being new is how to learn!

Comment: Thanks Leanne. I've got it working now by including first 2 lines. I'll wait for the above mentioned fix and switch to regex then (hopefully wil be before next year so I don't have to update all of our sources :)